# I am getting this error when i try to add bootstrap in my Angular project

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, angular14

[image]

I tried using following command too,

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap -- force
```

It didnt worked, so i deleted both **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** files.
I reinstalled it using following command.

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Still i am having the same problem. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

ng bootstrap isn't comptatible with angular 14 yet, if you whant to use it now you have to use angular 13

Answer (score 1):

I was following a tutorial, thats why i had to use those commands. insted i used this.

- I had to just install bootstrap on your angular 14 and import css
  file to style.css file. this is only for css importing. so you can
  run command bellow:

> npm install bootstrap --save

- then i imported bootstrap css on style.css file as like bellow:

> @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

[Referance link](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-install-bootstrap-5-in-angular-14example.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
You simpley do 

npm install bootstrap

and then map the respected soure location into your angular.json file 

"scripts": [ 
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
],
"styles": [
    "styles.css","./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]

And restart your app 
or
You can try with ngx also
```